# How to send jwt token for verfication while making a GET request

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, request, ejs

Basically I want to send a GET request which contains a header Authorization= jwt and then at server side this JSON web token is verified and a page should be rendered but if I make request using AXIOS or fetch than response is not render and if I use simple a tag to make request than how would I add header to it.
I am using NodeJS, ejs, express to render and vanilla JavaScript

Comment: With Header. If i not mistake with key `Authorization: Bearer <token>`

Answer (score 0):

Use following code before sending axios request.

```
axios.defaults.headers.common["Authorization"] = jwt;
```

Full code of express application with axios requests could be seen [here](https://github.com/fredeom/video_games_shop.git)

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can do with fetch

```js
fetch("http://....url", {
    method:"GET",
    headers:{
    ContentType:"Application/json",
    Authorization: jwt
    }
  }
).then(res => )
```